# Creating and Merging Linked Lists in C programming

Tags: c, merge, linked-list

We are given the main function and structures, asked to create two different linked lists. One being in ascending order and another in descending order and then joined together without changing their order. To give an example,if we have L1: 1->3->4->6 and L2: 9->8->5->2, The final list would be 1->9->3->8->4->5->6->2. This below is my work. I'm having some problems.

This is the main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#include "function.h"

struct nodeFB *startFB = NULL;
struct nodeGS *startGS = NULL;
struct newNodeFB *startNewFB = NULL;

int main()
{
    int id, age;
    scanf("%d", &id);
    while(id!=-1)
    {       
        scanf("%d", &age);
        insertFB(&startFB, id, age);
        scanf("%d", &id);
    }
    
    scanf("%d", &id);
    while(id!=-1)
    {       
        insertGS(&startGS, id);
        scanf("%d", &id);
    }
    
    printFB(startFB); 
    printGS(startGS);   
    createFinalList(&startNewFB,startFB,startGS);   
    printAll(startNewFB); 
    
    return 0;
        
}
```

These are the given structures and the functions I've written:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct nodeFB
{
    int id; 
    int age;
    struct nodeFB *next; 
};

struct nodeGS
{
    int id;
    struct nodeGS *next;
};

struct newNodeFB
{
    int id;
    int age;
    struct newNodeGS *next;
};

struct newNodeGS
{
    int id;
    struct newNodeFB *next;
};

struct nodeFB *startFB;
struct nodeGS *startGS;

//functions 

struct nodeFB *insertFB( struct nodeFB **startFB, int id, int age) 
{//address of the first node in the linked list of FB

    struct nodeFB *newnode, *ptr;

    newnode = (struct nodeFB*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodeFB));
    newnode->id = id;
    newnode->age = age;
    if (startFB == NULL) {
        newnode->next = NULL;
        *startFB = newnode;
    }
    else {
        ptr = *startFB;
        while(ptr->next!=NULL) {
            ptr=ptr->next;
            ptr->next= newnode;
            newnode->next = NULL;

        }
    }
    return *startFB;
}

void swap(struct nodeFB *a, struct nodeFB *b) {//function to swap two nodes
    int temp = a->id;
    a->id = b->id;
    b->id = temp;
}

void sortFB(struct nodeFB *startFB) { //function to bubble sort the given linked list
    int i;
    int swapped;
    struct nodeFB *ptr1;
    struct nodeFB *ptr2= NULL;
    if (startFB==NULL) { //checking for empty list
        return; }

    do {
        swapped = 0;
        ptr1=startFB;

        while (ptr1->next !=ptr2) {
            if (ptr1->id > ptr1->next->id) {
                swap (ptr1, ptr1->next);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            ptr1= ptr2->next;
        }
        ptr2=ptr1;
    }
    while (swapped);
    
}

void printFB(struct nodeFB *startFB) { //function to display the sorted list 
    struct nodeFB *ptr;
    ptr = startFB;
    sortFB(ptr);
    while(ptr != NULL) {

        printf("%d %d/n", ptr->id, ptr->age);
        ptr=ptr->next;

    }
}

struct nodeGS *insertGS(struct nodeGS **startGS, int id ) {
    struct nodeGS *newnode, *ptr;

    newnode = (struct nodeGS*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodeGS));
    newnode->id = id;
    if (startGS == NULL) {
        newnode->next = NULL;
        *startGS = newnode;
    }
    else {
        ptr = *startGS;
        while(ptr->next!=NULL) {
            ptr=ptr->next;
            ptr->next= newnode;
            newnode->next = NULL;

        }
    }
    return *startGS;
}

void swapGS(struct nodeGS *c, struct nodeGS *d) {//function to swap two nodes
    int temp = c->id;
    c->id = d->id;
    d->id = temp;
}

void sortGS(struct nodeGS *startGS) { //function to bubble sort the given linked list
    int i;
    int swapped;
    struct nodeGS *ptr1;
    struct nodeGS *ptr2= NULL;
    if (startGS==NULL) { //checking for empty list
        return; }

    do {
        swapped = 0;
        ptr1=startGS;

        while (ptr1->next !=ptr2) {
            if (ptr1->id < ptr1->next->id) {
                swapGS (ptr1, ptr1->next);
                swapped = 1;
            }
            ptr1= ptr2->next;
        }
        ptr2=ptr1;
    }
    while (swapped);
    
}
void printGS(struct nodeGS *startGS) {
    struct nodeGS *ptr;
    ptr = startGS;
    sortGS(startGS);
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%d/n", ptr->id);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

}

**struct newNodeFB *createFinalList(struct newNodeFB **startNewFB, struct nodeFB *startFB, struct nodeGS *startGS ) {
struct newNodeFB *temp1, *ptr1;
    temp1=(struct newNodeFB*) malloc(sizeof(struct newNodeFB));
    temp1->id= startFB->id;
    temp1->age=startFB->age;
    struct newNodeGS *temp2;
    temp2->id= startGS->id;
    struct newNodeFB *temp3 = NULL;
    struct newNodeGS *temp4 = NULL;
    while (temp1 != NULL && temp2 != NULL)
    {
        ptr1=temp1;
        while (ptr1->next!=NULL) {
            ptr1=ptr1->next;
            ptr1->next= temp2;
            temp2->next=NULL;
        }
    temp3=temp1->next;
    temp4= temp2->next;
    temp1->next=temp2;
    temp2->next=temp3;
    temp1=temp3;
    temp2=temp4;
    }
    startGS = temp2;
    return startNewFB;
}**

void printALL(struct newNodeFB *startNewFB){
    struct newNodeFB *ptr;
    ptr= startNewFB;
    while(ptr != NULL) {
    printf("%d %d/n%d", startNewFB->id, startNewFB->age, startNewFB->id);
    ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have two different lists and you want to merge them into a single list, then the simplest way is to just create the new merged list from scratch. Iterate over the first list and add the node data to the new (merged) list. Then do the same with the second list.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I haven't clarified, my bad, but we have two lists one sorted in ascending order while the other in descending. We want to add them together where we take one item from each list. For example if we have L1: 1->3->4->6 and L2: 9->8->5->2, The final list would be 1->9->3->8->4->5->6->2. I cannot quite grasp referencing another list's node in the structure of another as we were given above.

Comment: @Neil, I've edited the question but I will explain it here again. We want to add them together where we take one item from each list. For example if we have L1: 1->3->4->6 and L2: 9->8->5->2, The final list would be 1->9->3->8->4->5->6->2.

Comment: That is much clearer, thank you! This is like merge in mergesort, but alternating instead of picking the smallest.

Comment: @Neil, thank you! I also cannot understand how to reference the nodes from one structure to another as given in the structures above. Do I copy the data in the lists and create new lists, or?

Comment: It is your choice. In this case, I would use simply `struct node { unsigned age, id; struct node *next; };`. I'm not sure what `nodeGS` and `nodeFB` are; are you sure they are needed? One type can have multiple linked-lists.

Comment: @Neil, the structures have been given this way, and must not be changed.

Comment: Are you trying to merge different types of lists together? What is the use of `newNodeFB` and `newNodeGS`? They don't seem to correspond to the actual question. Are you supposed to create a new `nodeGS` from `nodeFB` by adding a default age and then merge the new node? Trying to create a virtual table of functions? Are you given the `main.c` and you have to write `function.h`?

Comment: @Neil, we were given the main.c function and the function.h with the structures where we must add our functions. basically, FB and GS are two different teams, and we want to take the data of each team and create a linked list of each, in the order that I have mentioned above, and then add them together, as was also mentioned before. It would've been easy if the references weren't the way they are.

Comment: How are you supposed to tell if a node is FB or GS in the final list?

Comment: @Neil, I think since NodeFB would have both ID and age and NodeGS would only have ID is what makes them different

Comment: Yes, but how will you tell the difference in your programme when you mix them together in one list? C doesn't have type-information built-in, and sooner or later, you are going to get a compile-time warning that you are assigning `struct newNodeFB *` with `struct nodeGS *`; it will crash for an entirely different reason, (what happens if `ptr = ptr->next` when it is really a `nodeGS`?)

Comment: Also, `malloc` is included in `stdlib.h`, `malloc.h` is not a thing since standardization by ANSI in 1989; the code they gave you would probably not compile anyway. Are you sure they'll mind, or notice, if you fixed it?

Comment: @Neil, I have added the following headers #include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

Comment: @Neil, the reason I have posted this question is that the problem I've been facing is this, receiving an error whenever I reach the point where I need to merge the lists

Comment: No matter what you do, you must have, at least, compatible list types to mix them together. The easiest way to make that happen probably depends on your specific assignment and what you are allowed to change. I would recommend just having two lists of `nodeGS` and merging into one `nodeGS`. That way you can concentrate on one thing at a time; types are an entirely different problem. Just ignore the age.

Comment: @Neil, can we copy the data of the two lists into one using a loop to go through the first list and then the second until we reach the end of both lists?

Comment: You don't need to copy, you can just rearrange them, as @Someprogrammerdude outlined in his answer. This will make a new list from the old lists. However, whenever you access it, it will crash, because you have lost information about what nodes are GS and what nodes are FB. The easiest solution, and one you should try first, is make all the lists one type, by making them all FB, filling in a default age for GS or by ignoring age.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to create a merged list where the nodes alternate, is to simply iterate over both lists simultaneously and add each node from the two lists into a brand new list.

Because you want to alternate between the two lists, you need to use a single loop to iterate the lists, adding one node from the first list to the new merge-list, then adding one node from the second list. Stop when both lists are finished.

In **pseudoish** code it could look something like this:

```
Node *node1 = list1->head;  // Node from first list
Node *node2 = list2->head;  // Node from second list

// Loop while there are nodes in at least one of the lists
while (node1 != NULL || node2 != NULL)
{
    if (node1 != NULL)
    {
        list_add_tail(merge_list, node1->data);
        node1 = node1->next;
    }
    if (node2 != NULL)
    {
        list_add_tail(merge_list, node2->data);
        node2 = node2->next;
    }
}
```

As seen it's basically the same as iterating over a single list, copying data to a new list.

Answer (score 0):

Another consideration is if one is mixing `struct nodeFB` and `struct nodeGS` in one list, how could the programme tell if the node is an *FB* or *GS*? Unless the lists are of equal sizes, where they are alternating, one loses type information by mixing them together.

There are several ways to get around this. One could only allow one type of node in one list; one has to convert the types to mix the lists. One might as well convert on input and have one type of list. A more nuanced approach is to store a pointer telling what type it is with every node.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* Circular definitions mean one has to forward declare. */
struct node;
static void foo_print(const struct node *);
static void bar_print(const struct node *);

/* Virtual table stores the type of node. */
typedef void (*print_fn)(const struct node *);
static const struct vt { print_fn print; }
    foo_vt = { &foo_print }, bar_vt = { &bar_print };

/* A list of nodes. */
struct node { struct node *next; const struct vt *vt; };
struct list { struct node *head; };

/* Subclasses of node. */
struct foo_node {
    struct node base;
    int id, age;
};
struct bar_node {
    struct node base;
    int id;
};

/* Implementations of the above. */
static void foo_print(const struct node *node) {
    const struct foo_node *ptr = (const struct foo_node *)node;
    printf("(foo)%d age %d", ptr->id, ptr->age);
}
static void bar_print(const struct node *node) {
    const struct bar_node *ptr = (const struct bar_node *)node;
    printf("(bar)%d", ptr->id);
}

static struct node *foo_input(void) {
    int id, age;
    struct foo_node *foo;
    if((printf("Id: "), scanf(" %d", &id) != 1) || id == -1
        || (printf("Age: "), scanf(" %d", &age) != 1)
        || !(foo = malloc(sizeof *foo))) return 0;
    foo->base.vt = &foo_vt;
    foo->id = id;
    foo->age = age;
    fprintf(stderr, "User entered %d, %d.\n", foo->id, foo->age);
    return &foo->base;
}
static struct node *bar_input(void) {
    int id;
    struct bar_node *bar;
    if((printf("Id: "), scanf(" %d", &id) != 1) || id == -1
        || !(bar = malloc(sizeof *bar))) return 0;
    bar->base.vt = &bar_vt;
    bar->id = id;
    fprintf(stderr, "User entered %d.\n", bar->id);
    return &bar->base;
}

//address of the first node in the linked list
static void push(struct list *start, struct node *node) {
    assert(start && node);
    node->next = start->head, start->head = node;
}

static void printAll(const struct list *list) {
    struct node *node;
    for(node = list->head; node; node = node->next)
    printf("%s", node == list->head ? "" : ", "), node->vt->print(node);
    printf(".\n");
}

/** Interleaves the list `bars` with the list `foos`. `bars` will be the empty
 list and `foos` will have all of the elements. */
static void createFinalList(struct list *foos, struct list *bars) {
    /* Create this function. */
    (void)foos, (void)bars;
}

int main(void) {
    struct list foos = { 0 }, bars = { 0 };
    struct node *node;
    while(node = foo_input()) push(&foos, node);
    while(node = bar_input()) push(&bars, node);
    printf("foos: "), printAll(&foos);
    printf("bars: "), printAll(&bars);
    createFinalList(&foos, &bars);
    printf("now,\n");
    printf("foos: "), printAll(&foos);
    printf("bars: "), printAll(&bars);
    /* fixme: Memory leak, clean up. */
    return 0;
}
```

If one really cannot modify the nodes, maybe encompass them in a `union`?

```
struct node {
    const struct vt *vt;
    union { struct nodeFB fb; struct nodeGS gs; };
};
```